# CS cart - Custom Field for add product in admin panel

Tags: cs-cart

Is it possible to add custom field in cs card for product?

I have added via back-end in product features

But it is not showing  in add product page. If any one tried this..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the template that you are using for your gateway..

check your data base for cscart_payment_processors and look for your payment name.

you'll then have 2 scripts one of them is the admin side and the second is the cart side.. you'll need to admin the cart side ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add the custom fields to Product add in Admin panel in the following file:

skins/[skin-name]/admin/views/products/update.tpl

And add your custom field you want with the cs-cart format:

Like:

And one more thing, you need to add the custom_field column in your DB, ?:products table.

Hope this resolve your issue.